# In operator in Where clause Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to carry out the following sql statement but I cannot perform my logic. How can I carry out `tl.HARDWARE_NUMBER IN (select t.HNumber from @HardwareNumberListTemp t)` part in the `where` clause?

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMER_NUMBER varchar(8)
DECLARE @HardwareNumberListTemp TABLE (HNumber VARCHAR(19))
DECLARE @BEGIN_DATE datetime
DECLARE @END_DATE datetime

/* there are some inserts into @HardwareNumberListTemp here */
SELECT  *   FROM abc.tatatable tl WITH(nolock)
            WHERE tl.INSERT_DATE BETWEEN @BEGIN_DATE AND @END_DATE
            -- the below part
            AND CASE WHEN @CUSTOMER_NUMBER IS NULL or @CUSTOMER_NUMBER = '' THEN TRUE
                ELSE  
                tl.HARDWARE_NUMBER IN (select t.HNumber from @HardwareNumberListTemp t)
                END
```

Comment: If you do find cases where you need to mimic a boolean in SQL Server *(which doesn't have a boolean data-type)*, you can use `CASE WHEN <x> THEN 1 WHEN <y> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1`, but it's non-SARGable and *can* be a significant performance hit.

Comment: You should also read this: https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html *(it's long, but you'll learn a **lot**)*

Comment: @MatBailie what a beautiful resource. Thank you. Of course, if god willing, I will.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions such as `THEN TRUE` will not work in SQL server. The `CASE` part could be written as:

```sql
AND (
    @CUSTOMER_NUMBER IS NULL OR
    @CUSTOMER_NUMBER = '' OR
    tl.HARDWARE_NUMBER IN (SELECT t.HNumber FROM @HardwareNumberListTemp)
)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think it? Yes, that's it.

Comment: Or just store your scalar variable as a row in your table variable. In short, you're making things harder by using 2 different variables as "parameters" to your query.